# Select network interface to be used by SftpClient class in SSH.NET

Tags: sftp, ssh.net

Is there any way to set local network interface to be used by SftpClient class in SSH.NET?

Comment: I need to replace FTP with SFTP. Code is using FtpClient class from Xceed FTP and there is a property LocalAddress that is used to select local network interface. I just try to find something similar in SftpClient from SSH.NET, but with no luck so far :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's not possible with the SSH.NET.

You would have to change implementation of the the [`SocketAbstraction.Connect` method](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/2016.1.0/src/Renci.SshNet/Abstractions/SocketAbstraction.cs#L50) to call [`Socket.Bind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.bind) before `Socket.ConnectAsync`.

---

Though are you sure you need to set the default interface?

An FTP client may need to use a specific network interface to listen on for incoming connecting in an active FTP mode. But for outgoing connections (SSH/SFTP uses outgoing connections only), one typically does not need to select a network interface.